# How can I check in which URL my node.js server is running?

Tags: node.js, url, endpoint

I have two servers :

1. db.mydomain.com and
2. db2.mydomain.com (for development)

How can I check which server is my code running at?

I want to do a backup of my data from the production one but not from the dev one. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the hostname in any request

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     var domain = req.headers.host;
     var parts  = domain.split(".");
     //assume www for no subdomain
     var subdomain = parts.length == 2 ? "www" : parts[0]; 
    ....
});
```