# How can I check in which URL my node js server is running?

Tags: node.js, express

I have moved my code to server via auto deployment, it will create dynamic sub domain.

I can see the console.log. Using this can we find node.js running url ?

I know i can get url in any request using req parameter. But i dont know any url to hit request.

```
const server = app.listen(3000, function(err) {
  console.log(
    "nodejs running url"+ url-should-print-here
  );
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with a debbug?

Comment: @AndyNope I'm new to nodejs, i dono what debug you are mentioning. i have updated my question. it will be more clear i think

Comment: Ahhh I see. Try with window.location.href to show the recent URL.

Comment: At first glance it seemed like this was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705602/how-can-i-check-in-which-url-my-node-js-server-is-running but I think you're actually talking about outside of the request/response loop.

Answer (score -3):

To output the recent URL:

```
const server = app.listen(3000, function(err) {
  console.log(
    "nodejs running url"+ window.location.href
  );
});
```

f you want your node server to respond to the URL http://www.example.com/updates, then you make your server listen on port 80 (the default port if no port is listed and the protocol is "http"). And, then you make your server respond to the "/updates" route.

Servers listen on a specific port at a specific IP address. They don't listen to a path or URL. The browser uses DNS to get an IP address for the host in the URL. If there's a port number in the URL, it uses that port. If not, it uses the default port for the specific protocol. It then makes a TCP connection to that IP address on that port. Then, if the protocol is http, it sends a request on that connection and includes the path.

So, the server receives the incoming connection and then as part of the HTTP protocol, it receives the verb (GET, POST, DELETE, etc...) and the path which it is then the servers job to decide what to do based on the incoming command/path.

```
const server = app.listen(80, function(err) {
  console.log(
    "nodejs running url"+ window.location.href
  );
});
```

Comment: Window object not declared error coming, do i need to import anything to work with window objects

Comment: `window` object is only available in browser.